# Single IP with multiple DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting

I have taken new account for dedicated server at SoftLayer.com. As per the terms and conditions they have to allot some set of dedicated IPs. After new account creation, I have hosted one web application on 202.65.36.45 IP (example) with ns1.softlayer.com DNS. Later I found that the same IP 202.65.36.45 is being used by other hosting providers with different DNS.

When I contacted support people they are telling that it is dedicated IP only but with different DNS.

If it is really a dedicated IP, is there any chance to configure single IP with multiple DNS? Otherwise these people are trying to cheat?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "I found that the same IP 202.65.36.45 is being used by other hosting providers with different DNS".

Comment: Showing us the commands that you ran might help us verify the situation.

Comment: Don't use existing IP addresses as example. Always use the real address (best solution) or official example addresses, in the prefix 192.0.2.0/24.

Comment: Very confused question, does not make a lot of sense. The OP should really read Kyle Brandt and Dan C comments and act on it (I really do not understand why it had two upvotes).

Answer (score 1):

You can host multiple websites on a single IP through the magic of [name based virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based).  Whether or not softlayer are "cheating" depends entirely on what precisely they've agreed to provide, and that's something you'd need to take up with them.  If their tech support is at all reasonable, then they should be able to clear up any confusion with you, and if they can't, then you perhaps need to reconsider whether they're suitably competent to provide you with hosting services.

Answer (score 1):

A single domain name should only have the authoritative DNS server specified by you. Meaning that any reverse DNS lookup should only resolve to those specified by you.

However, it is possible to configure different domain names, using different authoritative DNS servers each, that resolve to the same IP. In the hosting company, these differences are resolved using virtual hosting or shared hosting.

If the company had promised you a dedicated hosting including a dedicated IP, you should be the only one able to resolve to that IP. This can be checked by performing a reverse lookup of the IP and it should resolve to your domain name.

Maybe it was an honest mistake and some intern clicked on the wrong button.

Comment: Completely false. The standard, RFC 1035 asks for at least two name servers.

Comment: Alright, what I meant was an authoritative source for a domain name. Read in context. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This page answers your question pretty well: http://www.buildwebsite4u.com/articles/dedicated-ip.shtml

> Dedicated IP address (also called
>   static IP) means that a website has
>   its own IP address. Whether you type
>   in your URL or the numeric form of its
>   IP address, both will bring you to the
>   same domain.